# Вращение изображения c#

Tags: c#, изображения, picturebox, rotation

Всем привет, Сразу к делу : Моя задача вращать картинку в pictureBox (есть ракета, она должна плавно отклоняться на угол от -30° до 30° в зависимости от значения переменной причем вращение должно происходить вокруг заданной мною точки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
на данный момент у меня есть этот код, который работает не совсем правильно

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    public Image img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\image\Rocket1.png");
    public float rotationAngle;
    public Bitmap bmp;
    public Form1()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        int sizeWith = img.Size.Width;
        int sizeHeight = img.Size.Height;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, new Size(sizeWith, sizeHeight));
    }
    public void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { 
        rotationAngle = rotationAngle + 1;
        RotateImage(img, rotationAngle);

    }
    public void RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
    {

        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width, (float)bmp.Height);
            gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width, -(float)bmp.Height);
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gfx.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
            gfx.Dispose();    
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        }

    }
```

после всех этих махинаций у меня получается следующее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как исправить все это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий метод только image мерцает

```
 PaintEventArgs p = new PaintEventArgs(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(), pictureBox1.Bounds); //Компонент на котором нужно рисовать и область на которой нужно рисовать
 Rotate(sender, p);
```

с помощью данного кода мы запускаем наш метод

```
 public void Rotate(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {     
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img, img.Width, img.Height); // создаем новый битмап
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent); // трем старый рисунок
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(bitmap.Width /2 , bitmap.Height + 200); // перемещение в picturebox
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle / 1.5)); // угол вращения (Переменная RotationAngle)
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-bitmap.Width/ 2, -bitmap.Height - 200); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, bitmap.Width / 6, bitmap.Height / 6);     // проецируем изображение
    }
```

а это сам метод

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что вы рисуете на одном и том же Image => каждые поворот накладывается на предыдущий и вы получаете вот такой эффект.

Как вариант, создавайте новый `Image` и на нем отрисовывайте повернутое изображение.

Т.е у вас должно быть 2 `Bitmap`'а:

1. `Bitmap`, который хранит текущую повернутую картинку, которая в данный момент отображается
2. Чистый `Bitmap` на котором вы довернули до нового угла старый `Bitmap`.

После доворота, выставляете в `Control` новый `Bitmap`, а про старый забываете, вызвав `Dispose()`.

P.S В    `gfx.Dispose();` нету смысла, так как `using` это сам сделает.

Comment: Зачем? Есть же метод [`Clear`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.clear?view=netframework-4.8) который очищает поверхность.

Comment: Тогда очистится текущее изображение. Я к тому, что полюбому нужно 2 битмапа.

Comment: @ヒミコ метод Clear очищает полноcтью pictureBox, мне необходимо очистить лишь предыдущую версию рисунка

Comment: Не хранит оно предыдущую версию рисунка. Поэтому и советуют 2 битмапа.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вот в этом то и проблема, вы можете скинуть документацию как создавать новое изображение , я пробывал делать PixtureBox.Refresh(); , но он начинает ругаться на потоки и т.д.

Comment: 2 битмапа, спасибо попробуй

Comment: вы ничего не поняли, вернусь напишу ответ.

Comment: я правильно понял с двумя битмапами?   Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp2;

Comment: @ヒミコ я жду вас;3

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем скидываю решение, всем кто помогал спасибо

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Bitmap clone = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone()) 
        {
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
            {
                gfx.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                gfx.TranslateTransform(pictureBox1.Image.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Image.Height / 2);
                gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
                gfx.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, -pictureBox1.Image.Width / 2, -pictureBox1.Image.Height / 2);
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)clone.Clone();
        }
    }
```

вызов метода происходит с помощью

`Invalidate();`

Еще есть вот такая вот переменная(путь к картинке которую мы собираемся вращать)

```
 public Image img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\image\Rocket1.png");
```

которую мы в начале скрипта записываем в

```
   pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

данный метод вращает изображение на заданный вами угол т.е. если переменная rotationAngle = 30, то результат будет следующим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу скажу что при повороте изображение теряет качество
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чем больше вы его раз повернете тем хуже качество, пока решение этой проблемы не нашел( скорее всего качество теряется из-за того что мы поворачиваем уже повернутый объект,поэтому со временем картинка начинает терять качество, если при каждом повороте брать нашу начальную картинку, то я думаю потери качества можно избежать) надеюсь понятно и дословно объяснил.

Comment: Попробуйте такое перед манипуляциями с картинкой `gfx.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;`. Возможно поможет исправить потерю качества.

Comment: @Rootware, к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Напишем простой контрол для вашего случая:

```
public sealed class RotatableImage : Control
{
    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    private float _angle;

    public Bitmap Bitmap
    {
        get { return _bitmap; }
        set
        {
            _bitmap = value;

            if (_bitmap is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Invalidate(); // для вызова метода отрисовки OnPaint(...).
        }
    }

    public float Angle
    {
        get { return _angle; }
        set
        {
            _angle = value;

            if (_bitmap is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Invalidate(); // для вызова метода отрисовки OnPaint(...).
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Bitmap?.Dispose();

        if (disposing)
        {
            Bitmap = null;
            Angle = .0f;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public RotatableImage()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true; // что бы не было мерцаний.
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor); // можно изменить на любой другой, я использую фоновый цвет.

        if (Bitmap is null)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            return;
        }

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Bitmap.Width + .0f, Bitmap.Height + .0f);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Angle);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-Bitmap.Width + .0f, -Bitmap.Height + .0f);
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bitmap, new Point(0, 0));

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, добавьте новый контрол на форму.

Далее, определимся как будем загружать изображение, в моем примере, я его загружаю при помощи кнопки:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // привязываемся к изменению позиции трекбара, и передаем его в `RotatbleImage`
        RotatableImage.DataBindings.Add
        (
            new Binding("Angle", AngleTrackBar, "Value")
        );

        OpenBtn.Click += OpenBtnOnClick;
    }

    private void OpenBtnOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                RotatableImage.Bitmap = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
            {
                RotatableImage.Bitmap = null;

                MessageBox.Show
                (
                    fileNotFoundException.Message,
                    Resources.FileNotFoundCaption,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаем приложение, открываем изображение, двигаем трекбар.

Результат:

[image]

---

P.S. Зеленый фон... Баг программы записи.

Comment: обязательно использовать Control?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно, но желательно, можете наследоваться от PictureBox'a например, и переопределить его метод отрисовки, добавить поля, и все что вам необходимо.