# Вращение изображения в PictureBox c#

Tags: c#, изображения, picturebox, rotation, rotate

возникла проблема с вращение изображения в pictureBox. У меня есть изображение и я вращаю его в форме (угол вращения задаю с помощью trackbara), хочу это вращение выполнить в pictureBox, но к сожалению все мои попытки тщетны, и изображение никак не хочет вращаться, подскажите как данное вращение сделать в PictureBox, буду очень благодарен

```
 public Image img;
    public int RotationAngle;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true; // убираем мерцание
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\image\Rocket.png");


    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img, img.Width, img.Height); // создаем новый битмап
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(bitmap.Width * 5, bitmap.Height + 200 ); // перемещение в форме
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle/ 1.5)); // угол вращения
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-bitmap.Width / 2, -bitmap.Height - 200); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, bitmap.Width/6,bitmap.Height/6); // проецируем изображение
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RotationAngle = trackBar1.Value;
        Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Вам наверно стоит описать что вам не понравилось из вашего предыдущего вопроса, ибо там вам вроде описали подробную логику, даже контролл  создали и у вас опять точно такой же по сути вопрос. Пока лично я оцениваю его как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048936/).

Comment: в данный момент мне просто необходимо вращать изображение в picturebox, без использования всяких дополнительных классов, если у вас есть пример или решение данной проблемы, пожалуйста объясните мне

Comment: @Marz9n, Я же вам уже писал про то что вы можете наследоваться от класса `PictureBox`'a и рисовать в нем... Что вам мешает это сделать так, как я вам показал?

Comment: @ヒミコ ваше решение мне не подходит, в вашем случае если я проецирую изображение в pictureBox, то возникает мерцание ( двойная буферизация при этом включена), после недели поисков решения данной проблемы я подозреваю что идеального решения моей ситуации просто не существует, на данном этапе у меня есть код, который работает как мне надо, но bitmap в этом коде не выходит из памяти, как следствие забивает полностью оперативку, если я делаю Dispose, то pictureBox естественно будет пустым, но такое решение обладает не только таким недостатком, комментарием к посту скину код

Answer (score 0):

Код выглядит следующим образом

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\image\Rocket.png");
      //  pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\image\1.gif");
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }


    public void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {  
         Test();
    }
    public void Test()
    {

      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height); // создаем новый битмап  
      this.Invoke(new Action(() => bitmap.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution)));
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            gfx.TranslateTransform(pictureBox1.Width / 2 , pictureBox1.Height/2 +400); // перемещение в picturebox
            gfx.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle / 1.5)); // угол вращения (Переменная RotationAngle)
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-pictureBox1.Width / 2, -pictureBox1.Height/2 -600); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
            gfx.DrawImage(img, pictureBox1.Width/4, pictureBox1.Height/4);     // проецируем изображение                                                                    
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

    }
```

[image: Вот ошибка возникающая когда оперативная память забивается на 1гб]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так вот если я делаю

```
bitmap.Dispose;
```

то picturebox выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public void Test()
    {

      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height); // создаем новый битмап  
      this.Invoke(new Action(() => bitmap.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution)));
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            gfx.TranslateTransform(pictureBox1.Width / 2 , pictureBox1.Height/2 +400); // перемещение в picturebox
            gfx.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle / 1.5)); // угол вращения (Переменная RotationAngle)
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-pictureBox1.Width / 2, -pictureBox1.Height/2 -600); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
            gfx.DrawImage(img, pictureBox1.Width/4, pictureBox1.Height/4);     // проецируем изображение                                                                    
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        bitmap.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Ну и что это за ерунда? Где наследование от класса `PictureBox`?

Comment: Далее, зачем вы используете `Bitmap` как область рисования? Почему вы не делаете это в методе `OnPaint`, не трогая оригинальный `Bitmap`?

Comment: @ヒミコ я же вам объяснил почему я не использую OnPaint (сильное мерцание)

Comment: @ヒミコ выложил еще один ответ, с Onpaint

Comment: Это не метод `OnPaint`! Где наследование?

Comment: @ヒミコ возможно я реально чего то не догоняю, тогда прошу мне объяснить если это возможно

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще один пример кода

```
   public void Rotate(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Teal);
           this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh()));
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img, img.Width, img.Height); // создаем новый битмап   
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(bitmap.Width /2 , bitmap.Height + 200); // перемещение в picturebox
          e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle / 1.5)); // угол вращения (Переменная RotationAngle)
           e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-bitmap.Width/ 2, -bitmap.Height - 200); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
           e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, bitmap.Width / 6, bitmap.Height / 6);     // проецируем изображение
          bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я же вам уже 100 раз сказал про наследование! Почему вы даже не попробовали наследоваться от класса `PictureBox`？

Все делается буквально за минуту:

```
public sealed class RotatablePictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private float _angle;

    public RotatablePictureBox()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    public float RotationAngle
    {
        get { return _angle; }
        set
        {
            _angle = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Image is null)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            return;
        }

        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Width / 2.0f, Height / 2.0f + 400);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(RotationAngle / 1.5f);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-Width / 2.0f, -Height / 2.0f - 600.0f);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Width / 4, Height / 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: при попытке добавить этот класс в конструктор возникает ошибка

Comment: Перед добавлением, нажмите `ctrl + shift + b` Об этом я тоже писал в прошлом посте.

Comment: именно это я и сделал

Comment: Служба System.Windows.Forms.Design.ISelectionUIService уже существует в контейнере службы. Имя параметра: serviceType

Comment: предположим, а как вызывать этот класс из form?

Comment: я так и не догнал, ну создал я класс, а толку то от него, мне необходимо в него передавать переменную с картинкой, координаты из другого класса, но и еще каким то образом выбрать pictureBox в котором будут происходить изменения, а как это сделать я к сожалению не знаю, вы бы хоть ссылок чтоль накидали на статейки разные где я бы мог извлечь для себя нужную мне информацию, а вообще спасибо за ответы, и что потратили на меня свое время